# Iterate through LINQ AnonymousType object

Tags: c#, linq

How to use the result of this LINQ in another method and get the properties `CountryID` and `count`?

```
public IQueryable GetRequestsByRegion(string RequestType)
{
        try
        {
            var q = from re in context.RequestExtensions
                    from r in context.Requests
                    where re.ExtensionID == r.ExtraInfoID
                    && r.OriginalRequestID == null
                    && r.RequestType == RequestType
                    group re by new { CountryID = re.CountryID } into grouped
                    select new { CountryID = (int)grouped.Key.CountryID, count = (int)grouped.Count(t => t.CountryID != null) } ;

            return q;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return null;

    }

public void GetAllInformationRequestsByRegion()
    {
        IQueryable dict = GetRequestsByRegion("tab8elem1");

        /* How to iterate and get the properties here? */

    }
```

The return types and variable types don't need to be the ones indicated... This was just my try. I am also using WCF so I can't return Object types.

Answer (score 6):

Just like as if it were any other kind of object:

```
foreach(var obj in q) {
    var id = obj.CountryID;
    var count = obj.count;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not writing this immediately, handeling so many things it slipped: I want to use this inside a function, return the result of the LINQ without preprocessing it and deal with it on other methods. What type should I return in thie method and how to deal with the object on the calling methods? Also, using WCF so not able to return Object types... Thank you and sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: @LuísSousa: You could stop at `select g;` and return an `IGrouping<int, Request>`. If you want to return "final" objects, you should make a class for them.

Answer (score 2):

**Additional**

Perhaps you want to use this outside the method? Then use something like this:

```
public void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> l, Action<T> a)
{
  foreach (var e in l) a(e);
}
```

Usage:

```
ForEach(from x in bar select new { Foo = x, Frequency = 4444, Pitch = 100 }, 
  x => 
  { 
    //do stuff here
    Console.WriteLine(x.Foo);
    Console.Beep(x.Pitch,x.Frequency);
  });
```

Comment: I 'm considering a downvote for advocating a mutating `ForEach`... ;-)

Comment: @Jon: as the return type is `void`, I find it semi-acceptable :)  (Side note: I dont think I ever used such a construct)

Comment: trying this right now. Still not certain about what type of object to return in the LINQ method... Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite figure out how to use your method with my object... In my original code, how should I return variable `q` (what return type should the method have? Should I just return q or q.ToList()?) so I can pass it on to the method you said?

Comment: @LuísSousa: `q` should be fine.

Comment: @LuísSousa: The delegate has no return type, it is `void`.

Comment: @leppie: can you review my code on the question? I added more stuff so the question is clearer I hope...

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the result as you would a regular C# object. Intellisense will help you out with  the anonymous typing.

```
foreach (var anonymousObject in q)
{
    // anonymousObject.CountryID;
    // anonymousObject.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are local to the method that they are declared in. You can't return them directly. If you need them to be exposed outside of the declaring method, you need to project into a type that you can name (either your own custom class or some other existing framework class like KeyValuePair).